# PowerBI PowerQuery If Then statement, Else is not working

Tags: powerquery

I have a table that should have the [Line_of_Business] column populated from another system.  But some fields are null.  I added the following steps to clean that up by inferring the [Line_Of_Business] based on the [Primary_Technology]. I added the below "If" Statement code to correct the data and used a default value for the "else" but there are still remains some with null value.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"UNKNOWN Region",
    each [LINE_OF_BUSINESS],
    each
    if  
        ([LINE_OF_BUSINESS] is null) then
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Print Management")) then "DIR" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Office Solutions")) then "DIR" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Scan Capture Route")) then "DIR" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Workplace of the Future")) then "DIR" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Fax Solutions")) then "DIR" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Digital WorkPlace")) then "DIR" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "AppDev")) then "MIT" else
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Cloud")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Messaging")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Networking")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Security")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Server")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Service")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Virtualization")) then "MIT" else 
      if (Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY], "Other")) then "MIT" else "DIR"

      else
      [LINE_OF_BUSINESS] ,
Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"LINE_OF_BUSINESS"})
```

[image]

Comment: Since your data shows the entire column for both `[Line of Businees]` and `[Primary Technology]` equals *`null`*, your result is bound to be *`null`*. I'm surprised your code did not return an error message, though, as you are missing the fifth argument of the `Table.ReplaceValue` function.

Comment: Agree with Ron - what is your expected result?

Comment: This isn't the entire column.  It is just filtered to show what did not convert.  There were a few hundred rows that changed properly, these did not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your posted table has no relevance to your problem,
I would suggest creating a Replacement Table, and using that instead of a long `IF` statement.

For example:

[image]

Then you can use code like this:

```
let

//Read in Data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"LINE_OF_BUSINESS", type text}, {"PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY", type text}}),

//Read in Replacements Table
    #"Replace Table" = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Replacements"]}[Content],
    Replacements = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replace Table",{{"Old", type text},{"New", type text}}),

//Replace nulls in LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    #"Replace Nulls" = List.Accumulate(
        List.Buffer(List.Zip({Replacements[Old], Replacements[New]})),
        #"Changed Type",
        (s,c)=> Table.ReplaceValue(
            s,
            null,
            each if Text.Contains([PRIMARY_TECHNOLOGY],c{0}) then c{1} else [LINE_OF_BUSINESS],
            Replacer.ReplaceValue,
            {"LINE_OF_BUSINESS"}
        )),

//REPLACE REMAINING nulls
    #"Replace remaining nulls" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replace Nulls",
        null,
        "DIR",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"LINE_OF_BUSINESS"}
    )
in
    #"Replace remaining nulls"
```